# How to select row from Database by ID only once

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create an explore page for my social website and I have it kind of right. I select the posts by random order and it works but the thing is, I get the same post more than once. How do I select a post randomly by the id one time only ?

So basically I just want to load the post one time only in my explore page. Currently it could load more than once.

```
public function loadExplorePosts($data, $limit) {
    $page = $data['page'];
    $userLoggedIn = $this->user_obj->getUsername();
    
    if ($page == 1) {
        $start = 0;
    } else {
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    }
    
    $str = ""; //String to return
    
    $data_query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE deleted="0" GROUP BY id ORDER BY RAND()');
    $data_query->execute();
    $data_query_result = $data_query->get_result();
    
    if ($data_query_result->num_rows > 0) {
        $num_iterations = 0; //Number of results checked (not necasserily posted)
        $count = 1;
    
        while ($row = $data_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $body = $row['body'];
            $added_by = $row['added_by'];
            $date_time = $row['date_added'];
            $imagePath = $row['image'];
    
            if ($userLoggedIn == $added_by) {
                //echo "Your post";
            } else {
                     
            //Prepare user_to string so it can be included even if not posted to a user
                if ($row['user_to'] == "none") {
                    $user_to = "";
                } else {
                    $user_to_obj = new User($this->con, $row['user_to']);
                    $user_to_name = $user_to_obj->getFirstAndLastName();
                    $user_to = "to <a href='" . $row['user_to'] ."'>" . $user_to_name . "</a>";
                }
    
                //Check if user who posted, has their account closed
                $added_by_obj = new User($this->con, $added_by);
                if ($added_by_obj->isClosed()) {
                    continue;
                }
    
                if ($num_iterations++ < $start) {
                    continue;
                }
    
                //Once 10 posts have been loaded, break
                if ($count > $limit) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    $count++;
                }
            
                $user_details_query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT first_name, last_name, profile_pic FROM users WHERE username = ?');
                $user_details_query->bind_param("s", $added_by);
                $user_details_query->execute();
                $user_details_query_result = $user_details_query->get_result();
    
                while ($row = $user_details_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
                    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
                    $profile_pic = $row['profile_pic'];
                } ?>
                <script> 
                    function toggle<?php echo $id; ?>(event){
                            
                        var target = $(event.target);
                     
                        if (!target.is('a') && !target.is('button')) {
                            var element = document.getElementById("toggleComment<?php echo $id; ?>");
                     
                            if(element.style.display == "block")
                                element.style.display = "none";
                            else
                                element.style.display = "block";
                        }
                                                    
                    }
    
                </script>
                <?php
    
                $comments_check = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?');
                $comments_check->bind_param("i", $id);
                $comments_check->execute();
                $comments_check->store_result();
                $comments_check_num = $comments_check->num_rows;
    
                //Timeframe
                $date_time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $start_date = new DateTime($date_time); //Time of post
                $end_date = new DateTime($date_time_now); //Current time
                $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date); //Difference between dates
                if ($interval->y >= 1) {
                    if ($interval->y == 1) {
                        $time_message = $interval->y . " yr";
                    } //1 year ago
                    else {
                        $time_message = $interval->y . " yrs";
                    } //1+ year ago
                } elseif ($interval->m >= 1) {
                    if ($interval->d == 0) {
                        $days = " ago";
                    } elseif ($interval->d == 1) {
                        $days = $interval->d . "d";
                    } else {
                        $days = $interval->d . "ds";
                    }
    
                    if ($interval->m == 1) {
                        $time_message = $interval->m . "m ". $days;
                    } else {
                        $time_message = $interval->m . "m ". $days;
                    }
                } elseif ($interval->d >= 1) {
                    if ($interval->d == 1) {
                        $time_message = "Yesterday";
                    } else {
                        $time_message = $interval->d . " days ago";
                    }
                } elseif ($interval->h >= 1) {
                    if ($interval->h == 1) {
                        $time_message = $interval->h . "hr";
                    } else {
                        $time_message = $interval->h . "hrs";
                    }
                } elseif ($interval->i >= 1) {
                    if ($interval->i == 1) {
                        $time_message = $interval->i . "min";
                    } else {
                        $time_message = $interval->i . " mins";
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($interval->s < 30) {
                        $time_message = "Just now";
                    } else {
                        $time_message = $interval->s . "sec";
                    }
                }
    
                if ($imagePath != "") {
                    $parts = explode('.', $imagePath);
                    $extension = array_pop($parts);
    
                    if ($extension == 'mp4') {
                        $imageDiv = "<div class='postedImage'>
                                     <video width='670' height='415' controls>
                                        <source src='$imagePath' type='video/mp4'>
                                    </video></div>";
                    } elseif ($extension == 'gif' || 'png' || 'jpg' || 'jpeg') {
                        $imageDiv = "<div class='postedImage'>
                                        <a data-fancybox='gallery' href='$imagePath'><img src='$imagePath'></a>
                                    </div>";
                    } else {
                        echo "Couldn't load file";
                    }
                } else {
                    $imageDiv = "";
                }
    
                $str .= "<div class='status_post' onClick='javascript:toggle$id(event)'>
                            <div class='post_profile_pic'>
                                <img src='$profile_pic' width='50'>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class='posted_by' style='color:#ACACAC;'>
                                <a href='$added_by'> $first_name $last_name </a> $user_to &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$time_message
                            </div>
                            <div id='post_body'>
                                $body
                                <br>
                                $imageDiv
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class='newsfeedPostOptions'>
                                Comments($comments_check_num)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <iframe src='like.php?post_id=$id' scrolling='no'></iframe>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
                        <div class='post_comment' id='toggleComment$id' style='display:none;'>
                            <iframe src='comment_frame.php?post_id=$id' id='comment_iframe' frameborder='0'></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <hr>";
            }
        } //End while loop
    
        if ($count > $limit) {
            $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='nextPage' value='" . ($page + 1) . "'>
                        <input type='hidden' class='noMorePosts' value='false'>";
        } else {
            $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='noMorePosts' value='true'><p style='text-align: centre;' class='noMorePostsText'><center> No more posts to show! </center></p><br><br>";
        }
    }
    
    echo $str;
}
```

Comment: This seems to only get a given record once, are you calling this multiple times and thats what causes the repeats?

Comment: I don't believe so

Comment: Might be helpful https://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: Also you shouldn't use RAND() directly because it gives you a number between 0 and 1. This may need to unexpected behavior. Order by is expecting a table name.

Comment: That link only selects one post

Comment: So how should I load them randomly ?

Comment: If it's possible for you to let php do the work (e.g.) if you just load 10 posts, then you may use `shuffle()` by php.

Comment: First of all you should separate PHP, HTML and JS. This is difficult to read. Methods should also be rather small to make them easier to read. Try to split it into separate methods if needed.

Comment: Are you sure the posts are unique?

Comment: 100% positive. Unique id and file names

Comment: Then test this. Remove all the other code and after `get_result` do `var_dump($data_query_result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));`

Comment: @thatguyy Can you define "more than once" for us please? What results are you getting now, as opposed to desired results? Can you include a screenshot also? Plus, ping people directly as I did here for you. That way we know who you're responding to. I may not always be in the question and others also. To try and help answer this; have you trying `GROUP BY x`? and/or DISTINCT? Sometimes you need to use both. However, you have more than one SELECT here.

Comment: @Funkyfortyniner 'Sometimes you need to use both' that's not been my experience thus far

Comment: @Dharman I did that and var_dump shows the posts only once. So how should I do it with my code ? Put it piece by piece until I find the problem ?

Comment: Try to go through your code and identify at which point you see double results. It's not mysqli that gives you double results. It is your PHP/HTML displaying it twice.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I did that and it didn't work. By more than once I mean multiple times

Comment: @Dharman Ok I'll do it now

Answer (score -1):

You should use something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;
```

It is used to select the specified columns only once (distinct)

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score -2):

If you try with a subquery like :

`SELECT * FROM    ( SELECT * FROM    posts WHERE  deleted="0" ORDER BY rand() ) a GROUP BY id`

Comment: Still loads the same post twice

Comment: don't know why there is a random downvote ..
You could use DISTINCT but group by is an elegant way to do the same.

Comment: Don't know too. Group by is also a possible way. But another question is why the post is even loaded twice.

Comment: @TarikWeiss Should I post the whole function ?

Comment: @thatguyy Yes, please. What you have in question should give you only unique records

Comment: In mysql ORDER BY actually expects a table column name instead of a number.

Comment: Not my DV, but _Try this_ answers are ALWAYS low-value posts on SO (even if they work) because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Comment: I did this `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE deleted="0" GROUP BY id ORDER BY id` and now it shows the posts in order

Comment: @TarikWeiss That is not entirely true. Where did you get this information from?

Comment: i've updated my answer, you could try with a subquery, i'm going to bed so hope your solution will be resolved by me or another one

Comment: @Dharman the www lol. Just joking, looked into documentation, thought that key has to be a column. But seems I understood wrong.

Comment: just came back >< , not `order by id` but `group by id`
time to bed now lol

Comment: @Handler that gave me the results but in order not by random